# Laravel how to get a value from previous page?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get a title name from the previous page. Just one thing, not form, not an array. Just one value.

My question: Does laravel offer us a simple solution without using `$request` in functions?

In laravel we can go back to the previous page easily with `->back()` or we can go next step with middlewares `$next`.
I know sending a data must be with post action. But previous page's values can be different.

edit1:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $localeCode = LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale();
    $updates = Update::latest()->limit(3)->get();
    $slug_id = InvestmentCategory::where('slug',$slug)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first()->id;
    #$category_slug = InvestmentCategory::where('slug', $slug)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
    $invest = Investment::where('category_id', '=', $slug_id)->first();
    $top_categories = InvestmentCategory::where('parent_id', '=', null)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(4)->get();
    $bottom_categories = InvestmentCategory::where('parent_id', '=', $slug_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(4)->get();

    return view('frontend.investments', compact('localeCode', 'updates', 'invest', 'top_categories', 'bottom_categories', 'slug'));
}
```

Comment: what value? use session..

Comment: for example i have 1 query and that array have 5 instance. I want to pull my title in that query result.

Comment: does the title is static or dynamic?

Comment: its dynamic sir.

Comment: can you show the controller code to view the page.

Comment: Controller added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168736/discussion-between-ab-ab-and-ali-ozen).